# Plugin Grid not loading/block doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2, plugin

So I have a plugin called *Vendor*/*PluginName*.

It's fairly simple and has a grid layout (view/adminhtml/layout/pluginname_index_grid.xml) that has the contents of ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="formkey"/>
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Vendor\PluginName\Block\Adminhtml\PluginName\Grid" name="admin.plugnname.grid"/>
    </container>
</page>
```

So locally it works, but one the server debug.log shows the following.

> main.CRITICAL: Class Vendor\PluginName\Block\Adminhtml\Pluginname\Grid does not exist [] []
>
> main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Vendor\PluginName\Block\Adminhtml\Pluginname\Grid [] []
>
> main.CRITICAL: Block admin.pluginname.grid throws exception and cannot be rendered. [] []

All of the folders and namespaces are correct which is making this strange.

It looks like Magento is taking the adminhtml path and only having the first letter being uppercase and ignoring the case provided in the XML?

Any advice would be helpful.